# Dropdown redirect with cookie and ability to being changed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies

I have searched many topics but I did not find the exact solution for my problem.

I need to create a dropdown which will be placed at whole website because you always can change your location to another city to see the offer. I would like to create a dropdown where customer selects his city for a local delivery. This dropdown will be placed at the intro page and at everypage with offer. After user selects the city then a cookie will be created and user will be redirected to page he selects. The city he selects should always remembered.

What is my problem? Let me explain.

Now when I select the city and for example its New York and my dropdown is located at New Yorks page aswel for city change I keep being redirected and it never ends. So I get infinity redirects.

Second thing which curently works. When you visit the main url adress for example --> example.com it should redirect you to your city if you have chosen your city before. So if you have selected New york before it should redirect you to example.com/kategoria-produktu/cadca/

To sum up:
Everything works great but when this dropdown is located at the whole site I keep being redirected at the page I have selected and that is what I need to eliminate.

Any ideas please?

My code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (localStorage && localStorage.country) {
    location = localStorage.country;    
}

function formChanged(form) {
    var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val !== 'non-value') {
      if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.country = val;
      }
      location = val;
    }
}
</script>

<FORM NAME="form1">
<select onchange="formChanged(this);" NAME="country" SIZE="1">
<OPTION VALUE="non-value">Select delivery city
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/cadca/">New York
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/brno/">Los Angeles
<OPTION VALUE="/kategoria-produktu/bratislava/">Tokyo
</select>
</FORM>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi , where is the code which make you redirect to some page ? Your js code currently just store value in localStorage there is no redirection code.

Comment: I put this code into header of website.
Now it works like you select from select box your category (city) for example when I select New York it redirects me to New York but It keeps redirecting me in some infinite redirect loop, thats the only problem.

This code keeps remembered my last option Ive select so Im always loaded to New York page which is corect but what I need to do is to eliminate infinite page reload. So customer can choose another location for example LA. Redirect is called from option value and /kategoria-produktu/cadca is URL where it redirects you after you select NY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by editing code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href.indexOf(localStorage.country) == -1){
location.href = localStorage.country
}

function formChanged(form) {
var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
if (val !== 'non-value') {
if (localStorage) {
localStorage.country = val;
}

if (!location.href.indexOf(val)) {    
location = val;
}
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check, if the current location is equal to the target location:

```js
function formChanged(form) {
  var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
  if (val !== 'non-value') {
    if (localStorage) {
      localStorage.country = val;
    }

    if (!location.href.indexOf(val)) {    
      location = val;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im newbie in js, so I dont understand well could you provide a demo so I could check on it? Thank you

Comment: after I have replaced your function I still get infinity redirect loop